# Display today's date in datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

Anyone here how do I display today's date in jquery datepicker? Tried these but it doesn't display today's date in datepicker.

```
$('#from').datepicker({ 
    defaultDate: new Date(), 
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd', 
    onSelect: function () { 
       table.draw(); 
    }, 
    changeMonth: true, 
    changeYear: true 
});

$('#to').datepicker({ 
    defaultDate: new Date(), 
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd', 
    onSelect: function () { 
       table.draw(); 
    }, 
    changeMonth: true, 
    changeYear: true 
});
```

Comment: fill default date value in input directly.  or try `setDate`

Comment: `defaultDate:` - *Set the date to highlight on first opening if the field is blank* .. *or null for today*. https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-defaultDate

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setDate` like below.

```
$("#from").datepicker().datepicker("setDate", new Date());
```

```js
$('#from').datepicker({
  defaultDate: new Date(),
  dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
  onSelect: function() {
    //table.draw();
  },
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true
});
$("#from").datepicker().datepicker("setDate", new Date());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" media="screen" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="from" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the default date via

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker( "setDate", "10/12/2012" );
```

see: https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-setDate